# Excel Offset - Consolidate data from few excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Updated on 3 Oct 2018:**

I just retried my function, it manage to pull all data from the Facebook tab to the consolidated sheet.

> =offset('Facebook'!A2,0,0,ROWS(A:D),4)

I wish to insert the data from Instagram right below the Facebook data. Instagram data can be extracted using function below:

> =offset('Instagram'!A2,0,0,ROWS(A:D),4)

My question is, how do I combine the 2 functions into one, something like below? (example below is not working.... )

> =concatenate (offset('Facebook'!A2,0,0,ROWS(A:D),4),offset('Instagram'!A2,0,0,ROWS(A:D),4))

Thank you...

---

**On 2 Oct 2018:**

I have an excel file with 3 sheets (Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn), each sheet has the same data column as below:

> Date, Impressions, Clicks, Cost

I would like to consolidate the information on 1 sheet where it will show information with the columns below:

> Date, Impressions, Clicks, Cost, Platform

I have tried to extract the data from the Facebook sheet to the consolidated sheet by using offset function, however it only extract the 1st column data.

> =offset('Facebook'!A2,0,0,ROWS(A:D))

Can anyone please help to enlighten me? I have been researching for solution for almost 2 hours but it is not working still.

Thank you.

Comment: no, this is not a one time consolidation, the other sheets will be updated daily...

Comment: What's wrong with using regular reference formulas ("=Facebook!A2", "=Facebook!B2", ...)?

Comment: the other sheets are updated daily, so there will be additional lines on each sheet everyday.. i wish to use the offset function to make it auto extract the data everyday, but i haven't got the solution yet

Comment: The `offset` function won't know how many rows it needs to extract. Nor will any built-in function. What are you trying to do with `ROWS(A:D)`? It doesn't give you the last non-empty row of a sheet.

Comment: I'm able to pull all the rows using ROWS(A:D) ..., but the columns data is not extracted correctly

Comment: ROWS(A:D) doesn't work for me. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a multi-stage approach. In your Overview sheet,

```
[[Overview sheet]]
1       A             B       ...    E
2 =Facebook!A2  =Facebook!B2  ...  "Facebook"
3 =Facebook!A3  =Facebook!B3  ...  "Facebook"
```

And in columns G,H,I,J,K, you'd do the same for Instagram.

```
1       G             H       ...    K
2 =Instagram!A2  =Instagram!B2  ...  "Instagram"
3 =Instagram!A3  =Instagram!B3  ...  "Instagram"
```

Note: If you're trying to concatenate the contents of Facebook, Instagram, and LinkedIn, you can't do this with a formula without knowing the number of rows of data beforehand. I suppose you could use `=counta(Facebook!A:A)`, but your equations are about to get nasty really quick trying to have if-then logic to cascade between 3 sheets.

If you go that route, you'll also want to learn about:
INDIRECT
ADDRESS
CELL
and potentially MATCH, VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP